# Problem Saving with Entity Framework (Need conceptual help)

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, ado.net-entity-data-model, entity-framework-ctp5

**Problem Summary:** I have a Master and Detail entities. When I initialize a Master (myMaster), it creates an instance of Details (myMaster.Detail) and both appear to persist in the database when myMaster is added. However, when I reload the context and access myMasterReloaded.detail its properties are not initialized. However, if I pull the detail from the context directly, then this magically seems to initialize myMasterReloaded.detail. I've distilled this down with a **minimal unit test example** below. Is this a "feature" or am I missing some important conceptual detail?

```
//DECLARE CLASSES
public class Master
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]
    public Guid MasterId { get; set; }
    public Detail Detail { get; set; }
    public Master() { Detail = new Detail(); }
}

public class Detail
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]
    public Guid DetailId { get; set; }
    public Master MyMaster{ get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Master> Masters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Detail> Details { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Detail)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.MyMaster)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}

//PERFORM UNIT TEST
[TestMethod]
public void UnitTestMethod()
{
    //Start with fresh DB
    var context = new MyDbContext();
    context.Database.Delete();
    context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

    //Create and save entities
    var master = context.Masters.Create();            
    context.Masters.Add(master);
    context.SaveChanges();

    //Reload entity
    var contextReloaded = new MyDbContext();
    var masterReloaded = contextReloaded.Masters.First();

    //This should NOT Pass but it does..
    Assert.AreNotEqual(master.Detail.DetailId, masterReloaded.Detail.DetailId);

    //Let's say 'hi' to the instance of details in the db without using it.
    contextReloaded.Details.First();

    //By simply referencing the instance above, THIS now passes, contracting the first Assert....WTF??
    Assert.AreEqual(master.Detail.DetailId, masterReloaded.Detail.DetailId);
}
```

(This is the sticking point for a more sophisticated entity set. I've simply distilled this down to its simplest case I can't simply replace details with a complex type).

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt Hamilton was right (See above). The problem was:

1. The Detail property should **not** be instantiated **within the constructor**, nor through the getters/setters via a backing member. If it's convenient to instantiate a Entity containing Properties in your new instance, then it may be helpful to have a separate initialize method which will not be automatically executed by the Entity Framework as it reconstructs objects from the database.
2. The Detail property needs to be declared **virtual** in the Master class for this to work properly.

The following WILL PASS (As expected/hope)

```
  public class Master
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]
    public Guid MasterId { get; set; }

    //Key new step: Detail MUST be declared VIRTUAL
    public virtual Detail Detail { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]
    public Guid DetailId { get; set; }
    //Set this to be VIRTUAL as well
    public virtual Master MyMaster { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Master> Masters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Detail> Details { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //This sets up a BI-DIRECTIONAL relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<Master>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Detail)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.MyMaster)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}


[TestMethod]
public void UnitTestMethod()
{

   var context = new MyDbContext();
   context.Database.Delete();
   context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

   //Create and save entities
   var master = context.Masters.Create();

   //Key new step: Detail must be instantiated and set OUTSIDE of the constructor
   master.Detail = new Detail();
   context.Masters.Add(master);
   context.SaveChanges();

   //Reload entity
   var contextReloaded = new MyDbContext();
   var masterReloaded = contextReloaded.Masters.First();

   //This NOW Passes, as it should
   Assert.AreEqual(master.Detail.DetailId, masterReloaded.Detail.DetailId);

   //This line is NO LONGER necessary
   contextReloaded.Details.First();

   //This shows that there is no change from accessing the Detail from the context
   Assert.AreEqual(master.Detail.DetailId, masterReloaded.Detail.DetailId);
   }
```

Finally, it is also not necessary to have a bidirectional relationship. The reference to "MyMaster" can be safely removed from the Detail class and the following mapping can be used instead:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Master>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Detail)
            .WithMany()
            .IsIndependent();
```

With the above, performing context.Details.Remove(master.Detail), resulted in master.Detail == null being true (as you would expect/hope).

I think some of the confusion emerged from the X-to-many mapping where you can initialize a virtual list of entities in the constructor (For instance, calling myDetails = new List(); ), because you are not instantiating the entities themselves.

Incidentally, in case anyone is having some difficulties with a one-to-many unidirectional map from Master to a **LIST** of Details, the following worked for me:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Master>()
             .HasMany(x => x.Details)
             .WithMany()
             .Map((x) =>
                      {
                           x.MapLeftKey(m => m.MasterId, "MasterId");
                           x.MapRightKey(d => d.DetailId, "DetailId");
                       });
```

Cheers, Rob

Answer (score 2):

I *think* it's because when you first reload the **Master**, you have not eager-loaded the **Detail**, so the **Detail** entity will not be in the Entity Framework "graph" (internal memory). The only thing in the graph will be a single **Master** entity.

But when you *query* the **Detail** ("Let's say hi"), it is loaded into the graph and the reference was resolved based on the FK association, therefore your final test passes as the **Master** is now related to the **Detail**.

I could be wrong though - but that's what it sounds like.

Do you have **lazy-loading** enabled? If not, you need to eager-load the relationships you need.

Instead of this:

```
var masterReloaded = contextReloaded.Masters.First();
```

Try this:

```
var masterReloaded = contextReloaded.Masters.Include(x => x.Detail).First();
```

Comment: That and the fact that any new Master will automatically create a new Detail (in its ctor), so loading a Master from the database will try to create a new Detail instance.

Comment: Unless EF4 somehow bypasses the default ctor when instantiating entities. Anything's possible I guess.

Comment: Yup. Shouldn't be creating entities in the ctor. Let EF do what it's designed to do.

Comment: Well it looks for a parameterless constructor, which this one does - so that's what it will use.

Comment: Matt, thanks, it looks like that was the magic formula. I'm posting the details in the Answer box below.